# How to dynamically add points on the ILNumerics form?

Tags: .net, plot, drawing, ilnumerics

I want to dynamically calculate elements of Array and after each iteration put those points on the ILNumerics form. Is it possible?

UPDATE:

this is my code.

Initialize N:

```
 private const int N = 20000000;
```

This is a function that store data in array and then send it to the function named "Draw"

```
        public void Calc()
    {
        float o = (float) Math.PI/6;
        float lambda;
        const float hLambda = 0.02f;
         const float hAlpha = 0.02f;
        float alpha = (float) Math.PI/36;
        float[,] a;
        int i = 0;
        a = new float[N, 3];
            for (alpha = (float) 0; alpha < 6.2832; alpha += hAlpha)
                for (lambda = -1.8f; lambda <= 1.8f; lambda += hLambda)
                    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
                {
                    float xPaint = X_Sphere(lambda, o, alpha);
                    float yPaint = Y_Sphere(lambda, o, alpha);
                    float zPaint = Z_Sphere(lambda, o, alpha);


                    if (j > 900)
                    {
                        a[i, 0] = zPaint;
                        a[i, 1] = yPaint;
                        a[i, 2] = xPaint;
                        i++;
                    }
                    o = Calculate(o, lambda, alpha);
                }

            Draw(a, false);
    }
```

It's functon, which calculates data:

```
    public float Calculate(float o, float lambda, float alpha)
    {
        return (float) (lambda*Math.Sin(o + alpha));
    }
```

There I am transform coordinates from Spherical to Cartesian:

```
    public float X_Sphere(float r, float tetta, float a)
    {
        return (float) (r*Math.Sin(tetta)*Math.Cos(a));
    }

    public float Y_Sphere(float r, float tetta, float a)
    {
        return (float) (r*Math.Sin(tetta)*Math.Sin(a));
    }

    public float Z_Sphere(float r, float tetta, float a)
    {
        return (float) (r*Math.Cos(tetta));
    }

    private void Draw(float[,] obj, bool twodMode)
    {
        var cm = new ILColormap(Colormaps.Jet); 

        var scene = new ILScene();
        var pc = new ILPlotCube();
        var points = new ILPoints();
        points.Positions = obj;
        points.Size = 1f;
        ILArray<float> Z = ILSpecialData.sincf(10000000, 3, 4);
        var cmap = new ILColormap(Colormaps.Jet);
        points.Colors = cmap.Map(Z).T;
        points.Color = null;
        pc.TwoDMode = false;
        scene.Add(pc);
        pc.Add(points);
        pc.AllowRotation = true;
        pc.AllowZoom = true;
        scene.Screen.First<ILLabel>().Visible = false;
        ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
    }
```

Comment: What have you achieved so far? You can create dynamic plots. It is easy but depends on the kind of plot to generate.

Comment: I updated my post. 

At the moment I am calculating data that i need and than drawing it via ILNumerics. But there is a problem. It's an enormous amount of points which I need to draw, so I'm thinking, maybe I can draw it dynamically? 
I mean: 
- Draw one point
- Overwrite it
- Draw another
(And show all the points by this method on the screen?)


Because it's to useful of memory at the moment. 
Could you help me?

Comment: Hey, Haymo? Are you still here?

Comment: Sure. Your examples is too complex. The whole algorithm probably could be drastically reduced by using ILNumerics arrays and methods of ILMath instead of System.Array. But the only relevant part is the Draw function, I guess. See my answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for 'incremental updates'. You would modify the positions buffer for the shape via the `ILShape.Positions.Update(int startColumn, int count, ILInArray<T> data)` function. This saves performance by only updating the modified part of the video memory (expecting OpenGL renderer here).

However, the buffer must exist as one big memory segment in graphics memory. I suspect the bottleneck more to lay in drawing, not in the buffer definition. A profiler is your friend!

Don't forget to call ILShape.Configure() after all modifications!